# VS2015\IIS express cannot load external DLL

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem with Visual Studio and Web API. I need to use a DLL project that uses third part library (compiled for x86 o x64, I've used x86 version)

The DLL project is currently working in others applications without any problem, but when I add it to my Web Api project, during startup I receive an FileNotFoundException on a DLL (perhaps the first one of a bunch). The DLL is copied in bin folder. I can't figure out why IIS\VS can't find it.

Any idea ?!

Comment: Is third party library a COM dll or .Net assembly?

Comment: Is .NET assembly Wrapping a COM DLL. I know, worst case :(

Comment: And you are sure that COM dll is registered on machine in question?

Comment: All Dll required are in the bin, included the one that rise the exception